Sandisk SDHC erase in SPI mode problem
I am working in a little project in which the previous dev was using SD card in the SPI mode. The code was tested for SD init, read block, write block and erase and it worked fine with SDHC cards from Kingstone, Adata, Goodram etc., but when we switched to Sandisk we had some problems. Right now the only problem remaining is that I cant make the card go into erase mode (again, the code works with other cards). I tried to find documentation about working with cards in SPI mode, especially Sandisk to check if there ae any differences, but I could wrap my head around the problem.
So, when I try to erase the card I use the following commands: CMD32 to set the start block address which is 0, CMD33 that sets the end block address (in my case the previous dev wrote 116224, which is a multiple of 512) and CMD38 that starts the erase. In the case of the Sandisk sd cards it always fails after sending the CMD33 command. I tried to change the end address to smaller numbers, but it still failed. After sending the CMD33 I saw that the value returned from the register r1 I think is not 0 (success), but 224 (11100001).On some forums I read that it would be a good idea to send CMD9 to read some properties like erase_blk_en and sector_erase_size, but I cant make this work.
Do any of you have any idea what the problem might be? Or if any of you know that this might be a general problem with Sandisk cards?
